# How to count the visits of the last 7 days in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, date, count, window-functions

I have a sample table that capture user visits

```
User|Visit|Date--
Mike|01|1/9/2020--
Mike|01|3/9/2020--
Mike|01|10/9/2020--
John|01|12/9/2020--
John|01|20/9/2020--
Carl|01|16/9/2020--
Carl|01|18/9/2020--
Carl|01|20/9/2020
```

I want to create a MySQL query such that it captures all the fields/rows from *example* table and create an additional column "last 7Days". In this column, the idea is to sum all visits from the user from the last 7 days.

The outcome I'm looking out it is something like this

[image: Query_Image]

Comment: which version of mysql are you using?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @nbk I'm using the version 8.0.21

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use window function with `range`
check this out

```
select t.*, 
  sum(visit) over (partition by user order by `Date` 
    range between interval + 7 day preceding and current row  ) -1 as x
from t
```

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/daoRLoNsAvM6jJfkqYmxxM/0)

Answer (score 0):

you can do it with `ADDDATE()` function

```
$sql = 'SELECT count(Visit) FROM your_table_name WHERE Date BETWEEN ADDDATE(NOW(),-7) AND NOW()'
```

Comment: Use COUNT or SUM function

Comment: ADDDATE() function in sql